# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext SNI servername_cb Not Working

Tags: ruby, macos, openssl, sni, server-name

As referenced in [OpenSSL::X509::Certificate Showing Certificate for Wrong Domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30238304/opensslx509certificate-showing-certificate-for-wrong-domain), I need to use TLSv1 or above *and* [Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) extension.

Even with `ssl_version` and `servername_cb` set via the `SSLContext`, I'm still getting the wrong certificate for `myproair.com`.

```
  begin 
    timeout(1) do
      tcp_client = TCPSocket.new("#{instance["domain"]}", 443)
      ssl_context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new()
      ssl_context.ssl_version = :TLSv1
      ssl_context.servername_cb = "https://#{instance["domain"]}"
      ssl_client = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(tcp_client, ssl_context)
      ssl_client.connect
      cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(ssl_client.peer_cert)
      ssl_client.sysclose
      tcp_client.close
      #http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/X509/Certificate.html
      date = Date.parse((cert.not_after).to_s)
      row.push("#{date.strftime('%F')} #{cert.signature_algorithm} #{cert.subject.to_a.select{|name, _, _| name == 'CN' }.first[1]}".downcase.ljust(57))
    end
  rescue SocketError
    row.push("down".ljust(57))
  rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
    row.push("connection refused".ljust(57))
  rescue Errno::ECONNRESET
    row.push("connection reset".ljust(57))
  rescue Timeout::Error
    row.push("no 443 listener".ljust(57))
  rescue OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError
    row.push("bad certificate - ssl error".ljust(57))
  rescue Exception => ex
    row.push("error: #{ex.class} #{ex.message}".ljust(57))
  end
```

How do I set the server name in Ruby 2.0 on OS X?

---

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]

$ openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8zc 15 Oct 2014
```

Comment: `servername_cb` is for the server side. When the server gets a connection, it invokes the callback to allow the server to select a *SNI* related certificate :) On the client, you are looking for the Ruby equivalent to `SSL_set_tlsext_host_name`. You can see a C-based example of it at OpenSSL's [SSL/TLS Client](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client).

Comment: Also see [How to set TLS context options in Ruby (like OpenSSL::SSL::SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22550213). It shows you how to get "TLS 1.0 and above" in Ruby.

Comment: @jww thank you for all of your insights - I'm reaching into edge case territory but it's fun :) still digging around to find the Ruby equivalent...

Comment: Ruby is very frustrating to me. I find its too damn difficult to do basic things securely, like establish a secure channel. (I have my own definition of "secure" when it comes to secure channels). I eventually gave up on it and stopped trying to learn it.

Comment: After immersing myself in Ruby for the past few months, I've concluded the same thing - I'm debating rewriting in Python. What's your preference?

Comment: I need more info regarding this, I have a multi tenant app coded with rails , and each client will be uses their own domain. My problem is setting up SSL for my clients to access my app with their domain names.

From my research, all this happens at the server level.  So i am a bit confused when i see SNI at the rails level. So its possible to setup SNI for rails using the OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext#servername_rb ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Naturally you use the [undocumented](https://github.com/ruby/openssl/blob/master/lib/openssl/ssl.rb#L256) 'hostname' method for OpenSSL::SSLSocket!

```
tcp_client = TCPSocket.new("#{instance["domain"]}", 443)
ssl_context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new()
ssl_context.ssl_version = :TLSv1
ssl_client = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(tcp_client, ssl_context)
ssl_client.hostname = instance["domain"]
ssl_client.connect
cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(ssl_client.peer_cert)
ssl_client.sysclose
tcp_client.close
```

I discovered that [here](https://github.com/igrigorik/http-2/blob/master/example/client.rb) while writing code with a similar goal.